# Where to get X11 for OS X 10.6 without the installation CD?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, xorg, gimp

In order to get GIMP working on OS X I'm told to install X11 from CD. Unfortunately I don't have such a CD. Is there an other way to get X11 working for OS X?

---

If I start GIMP I do get the following error message. This happens with the built in (?) X11.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki), select your [release here](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/Releases).

> The XQuartz project is an open-source effort to develop a version of the  X.org X Window System that runs on Mac OS X. Together with supporting libraries and applications, it forms the X11.app that Apple has shipped with OS X since version 10.5.

Comment: When I try to install this package I get an error message, that my system doesn't need this update. However GIMP does not start. If I try it several times, I get an error message, that X11 is missing.

Comment: try a [different package](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/Releases) as [gimp recommends](http://www.gimp.org/macintosh/). What version of OSX are you on?

Comment: I have Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)

Comment: download [here](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/downloads/SL/XQuartz-2.6.3.dmg)

Comment: I downloaded the package and installed it. Loged out and back in again. No change, I still get the error message.

Comment: @BetaRide Try reinstalling gimp

Answer (score 1):

Install XQuartz,
do NOT logout,
open Gimp and wait until it opens COMPLETELY,
Then quit X11.
Re-open Gimp.

Post any error messages reported.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode comes with X11. The download is quite large (~4GB), but you should have it on the disc that came with your mac.

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: As stated in the question, I don't have this disc.

Comment: Create an account and download it then.